# Kotlin - Ktor - How to handle Optional API resource fields in PATCH calls?

Tags: rest, kotlin, option-type, ktor

When implementing a REST API with Ktor (and Kotlin), it supports the optional field handling of Kotlin. Which works for POST and GET, but what about PATCH (update)?

For example, you have the following resource:

```
@Serializable
data class MyAddress(
    var line1: String? = null,
    var line2: String? = null,
    var city: String? = null,
    var postal_code: String? = null,
    var state: String? = null,
    var country: String? = null
)
```

So all MyAddress fields are optional (with a default value).

When you create an address with POST:

```
   "line1" : "line1",
   "country" : "XX"
```

and you than want to remove the country with a PATCH:

```
   "country" : null
```

the end result of the resource should be:

```
   "line1" : "line1"
```

But how can you determine this by parsing the json of the PATCH request? Because there is no way, as far as I know, to determine if it was `null` by default, or submitted.

Furthermore, the default `null` value for the `MyAddress` is required, because else the parsing will not work.

Code example:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class MyAddress(
    var line1: String? = null,
    var line2: String? = null,
    var city: String? = null,
    var postal_code: String? = null,
    var state: String? = null,
    var country: String? = null
)

fun main() {
    val jsonStringPOST = "{\"line1\":\"street\",\"country\":\"GB\"}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringPOST")

    val myAddressPost = Json.decodeFromString<MyAddress>(jsonStringPOST)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressPost")

    val jsonStringPATCH = "{\"country\":null}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringPATCH")

    val myAddressPatch = Json.decodeFromString<MyAddress>(jsonStringPATCH)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressPatch")
}
```

I tried to add `Optional<String>?` as well, but it complains about missing serialization of `Optional`, and preferably I do not want to make all my data var's Optionals.

Note: I am looking for a more structured solution, that also works with all other resources in the API (10+ classes).

Comment: For the UPDATE request, I would receive a `JsonObject` and iterate through all known keys to determine how to update them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would indeed be an option, but when there is a layered structure (so with the MyAddress as a value of a Person, and a Person is a value of a Group, for example), you have to 'know' all the names of the keys. This is not really scalable, I think.

Comment: Then I see two options here. Either you make all properties nullable but without a default value and force your clients to send all keys every time or you work consistently only with JSON elements objects.

Comment: The first option will not really work, because that is not how REST should work from a user/API perspective.
I was hoping for a more structured solution. Like Kotlin had (it has been removed) an `Optional` annotation. Something like that, to have the same 'functionality' like a Java Optional; that you can determine 1) it was send with a value, 2) it was send with a `null` value, 3) it was not send

Answer (score 3):

A second solution, based on Aleksei's example:

```
@Serializable
data class Address2(val line1: OptionalValue<String> = Undefined, val country: OptionalValue<String> = Undefined)

@Serializable(with = OptionalValueSerializer::class)
sealed interface OptionalValue<out T>
object Undefined: OptionalValue<Nothing> {
    override fun toString(): String = "Undefined"
}
object Absent: OptionalValue<Nothing> {
    override fun toString(): String = "Absent"
}
class WithValue<T>(val value: T): OptionalValue<T> {
    override fun toString(): String = value.toString()
}

open class OptionalValueSerializer<T>(private val valueSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<OptionalValue<T>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = valueSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): OptionalValue<T> {
        return try {
            WithValue(valueSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
        } catch (cause: SerializationException) {
            Absent
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: OptionalValue<T>) {
        when (value) {
            is Undefined -> {}
            is Absent -> { encoder.encodeNull() }
            is WithValue -> valueSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val jsonStringPOST = "{\"line1\":\"street\",\"country\":\"GB\"}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringPOST")

    val myAddressPost = Json.decodeFromString<Address2>(jsonStringPOST)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressPost")

    val jsonStringUPDATE = "{\"country\":null}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringUPDATE")

    val myAddressUpdate = Json.decodeFromString<Address2>(jsonStringUPDATE)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressUpdate")
    if(myAddressUpdate.country is Absent || myAddressUpdate.country is WithValue) {
        println("Update country: ${myAddressUpdate.country}")
    } else {
        println("No update for country: ${myAddressUpdate.country}")
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
JSON string is: {"line1":"street","country":"GB"}
MyAddress object: Address2(line1=street, country=GB)
JSON string is: {"country":null}
MyAddress object: Address2(line1=Undefined, country=Absent)
Update country: Absent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [sealed interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) for a part of an address to represent undefined value, absence of value, and actual value. For this interface, you need to write a serializer that will encode and decode values accordingly to your logic. I'm not good at the `kotlinx.serialization` framework so I wrote an example as simple as possible.

```
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveKind
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveSerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 4444) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }

        routing {
            post {
                val address = call.receive<Address>()
                println(address)
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

@Serializable
data class Address(val line1: MyValue = Undefined, val country: MyValue = Undefined)

@Serializable(with = AddressValueSerializer::class)
sealed interface MyValue
object Undefined: MyValue {
    override fun toString(): String = "Undefined"
}
object Absent: MyValue {
    override fun toString(): String = "Absent"
}
class WithValue(val value: String): MyValue {
    override fun toString(): String = value
}

object AddressValueSerializer: KSerializer<MyValue> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("AddressValue", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): MyValue {
        return try {
            WithValue(decoder.decodeString())
        } catch (cause: SerializationException) {
            Absent
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MyValue) {
        when (value) {
            is Undefined -> {}
            is Absent -> { encoder.encodeNull() }
            is WithValue -> { encoder.encodeString(value.value) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksei! With some help of medium.com, I came to a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

With some help from medium.com, I came to the following solution:

```
@Serializable(with = OptionalPropertySerializer::class)
open class OptionalProperty<out T> {

    object NotPresent : OptionalProperty<Nothing>()

    data class Present<T>(val value: T) : OptionalProperty<T>() {
        override fun toString(): String {
            return value.toString()
        }
    }

    fun isPresent() : Boolean {
        return this is Present
    }
    fun isNotPresent(): Boolean {
        return this is NotPresent
    }

    fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
        return (this is Present) && this.value == null
    }
    fun hasValue(): Boolean {
        return (this is Present) && this.value != null
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        if(this is NotPresent) {
            return "<NotPresent>"
        }
        return super.toString()
    }
}

open class OptionalPropertySerializer<T>(private val valueSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<OptionalProperty<T>> {
     override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = valueSerializer.descriptor

     override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): OptionalProperty<T> =
        OptionalProperty.Present(valueSerializer.deserialize(decoder))

     override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: OptionalProperty<T>) {
        when (value) {
            is OptionalProperty.NotPresent -> {}
            is OptionalProperty.Present -> valueSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
private data class MyAddressNew(
    var line1: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
    var line2: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
    var city: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
    var postal_code: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
    var state: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
    var country: OptionalProperty<String?> = OptionalProperty.NotPresent,
)


fun main() {
    val jsonStringPOST = "{\"line1\":\"street\",\"country\":\"GB\"}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringPOST")

    val myAddressPost = Json.decodeFromString<MyAddressNew>(jsonStringPOST)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressPost")

    val jsonStringUPDATE = "{\"country\":null}"
    println("JSON string is: $jsonStringUPDATE")

    val myAddressUpdate = Json.decodeFromString<MyAddressNew>(jsonStringUPDATE)
    println("MyAddress object: $myAddressUpdate")
    if(myAddressUpdate.country.isPresent()) {
        println("Update country: ${myAddressUpdate.country}")
    } else {
        println("No update for country: ${myAddressUpdate.country}")
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
JSON string is: {"line1":"street","country":"GB"}
MyAddress object: MyAddressNew(line1=street, line2=<NotPresent>, city=<NotPresent>, postal_code=<NotPresent>, state=<NotPresent>, country=GB)
JSON string is: {"country":null}
MyAddress object: MyAddressNew(line1=<NotPresent>, line2=<NotPresent>, city=<NotPresent>, postal_code=<NotPresent>, state=<NotPresent>, country=null)
Update country: null
```

Comment: I like that you serialize/deserialize values of generic type but I don't like the nullable values for `OptionalProperty` objects and the fact that the `OptionalProperty` class is open. Also, `OptionalProperty<Nothing>()` looks weird.

Comment: I rewrote it to have a `sealed interface` instead of an `open class`, but not sure if a `sealed interface` will work through out my application.
And what would your suggestion be as alternative for `Nothing`, to solve the Generic value?

Comment: If you have a sealed interface then you can represent an absence of value and undefined value with objects like I did in my example.

Comment: In your example it indeed works, but if you add generics, it does not. You will have to pass in something for all 3 options, like:
`sealed interface OptionalValue<out T>`
and
`object Undefined: OptionalValue<Nothing>{ .. }`
`object Absent: OptionalValue<Nothing>{ .. }`
Else the serializer does not compile...

Comment: Yeah. When I tried to do it with generics I passed the `Any` value because any value can be undefined or absent.

Comment: I think I will still go for `Nothing` instead of `Any`, because when the value is `notPresent` there is indeed no value at all (so nothing), and not potentially something (or undefined or absent). Conceptionally that sounds better to me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

A third solution based on Etienne. It fixes an issue when the decoder is cannot be deserialised as T and throws. The base version maps to "Absent".

Also did rename the cases.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder

@Serializable(with = AbsentOrNullOrValueSerializer::class)
sealed interface AbsentOrNullOrValue<out T>

object Absent : AbsentOrNullOrValue<Nothing> {
    override fun toString(): String = "Absent"
}

object NullValue : AbsentOrNullOrValue<Nothing> {
    override fun toString(): String = "Null"
}

class WithValue<T>(val value: T) : AbsentOrNullOrValue<T> {
    override fun toString(): String = value.toString()
}

open class AbsentOrNullOrValueSerializer<T>(private val valueSerializer: KSerializer<T>) :
    KSerializer<AbsentOrNullOrValue<T>> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = valueSerializer.descriptor

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): AbsentOrNullOrValue<T> {
        return if (!decoder.decodeNotNullMark()) {
            NullValue
        } else {
            WithValue(valueSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: AbsentOrNullOrValue<T>) {
        when (value) {
            is Absent -> {}
            is NullValue -> {
                encoder.encodeNull()
            }
            is WithValue -> valueSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.value)
        }
    }
}
```